# Safari PDF Issue

Tags: safari, pdf

When I try to load a PDF in Safari I am getting some odd Asian (sorry I don't know what dialect) type in the loading window. My best guess is there is a font substitution occurring but I really don't know what is going on.

If there is a faint issue, maybe I have the needed font turned off? What font is the loader looking for.

If not a font issue, what is happening?

(Bonus: What language is it? And what does it say?)

[image]

Comment: That isn't an OS X loading overlay. I'm guessing Adobe Reader/Acrobat (but don't have either installed so can't be sure). (Also it's not Safari Reader, that's the article reading feature; removed tag)

Comment: @George Garside Thanks for removing the reader tag, you're right. I wasn't paying attention there.

Comment: take a look in you /Library/InternetPlugins Folder maybe you have installed a third party PDF Application which has installed a pdf plugin for Safari (Adobe Acrobat and PDF Architect do this) - it may also be a pdf viewer integrated on the server side - can you podt us the jrl of the pdf file???

Comment: Ok, so far it's nothing in the Plugins folder. I'm just looking around for something Adobe Acrobat related now. This loader text comes up any time I download a PDF in Safari.

Comment: Well, I went the nuclear route… I just deleted everything Adobe from the Safari Plug-ins. Back to good ol' Preview form my PDF's in Safari! I may revisit this in the future by trying to reinstall Reader plugins, but for now deleting everything will do.